# What is the easiest method for making an image plane half-transparent?

Tags: transparency

I'm just setting up an image and I have to use units, so I want to see the grid when looking from top. Currently the image blocks the grid. Just want to make the image a little transparent. Must I use shader properties etc?? I'm new to blender sorry

Comment: I saw some tutorials where it's easily done with reducing Alpha level somewhere but cant find that stuff in the new blender versions

Answer (score 3):

If you add material, it's a principled shader. Just turn down the alpha

[image]

And also 'Alpha blend' from the settings of that material:

[image]

And you may need to be in Material Preview or Display Render mode:

[image]

Comment: Principled shader works fine thank you. I wanted to do it without going into shader stuff, I think it must be possible to just reduce opacity in the viewport independent from shader?

Comment: It would be nice, yes - I don't know if that's possible :/

Comment: I also noticed that there is _display "In Front"_ option under object properties.. but there used to be an also alpha slider there.. I wonder why they removed it!?

Comment: @SadunKal Hello :). The alpha slider is only there if you add images through *Add > Image > Background/Reference*. Otherwise you'll have to use shaders.

Answer (score 1):

Set the viewport display to "Object" and then tweak the color alpha in the viewport display color property :

[image]